# AmCharts: How do i check if graph is hidden?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I got ONE balloon only in my chart, and I want to check if not only the graph it belongs to is hidden, but if ANY graph is hidden. How do I check this attribute?

```
function adjustBalloonText(graphDataItem, graph){
    var data = graphDataItem.dataContext;
    var date = ""; //some kind of getDateInScrollbar here
    console.log(graphDataItem);
    var distance = data.distance; // some kind of getGraphsValue here
    var duration = ""; // some kind of getGraphsValue here as well
    return distance;
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Why are you asking so much questions for basically the same? Can you please take some time (at least a few hours) and try to get this figured out on your own? As Martynas already mentioned this is not what SO is meant for.

Comment: Besides I've recreated a simple mock-up of my old custom balloon implementation. You can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nLa4auey/).